# ASP.net MVC - Get currently logged user role in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I know that there are a lot of topics about this issue but I already tried several solutions and cannot make it work.

So, I am trying to verify the currently logged user role in my view. As referred in the major part of topics about this in StackOverflow, I just have to do:

```
@User.IsInRole("Admin")
```

Unfortunately this always returns false even with the "Role" column, in the AspNetUsers table, of the current logged user is populated with "Admin".

I also tried below approach but it says that "UserManager does not exist in current context".

```
<p>@UserManager.GetRoles(userId)</p>
```

One of my suspects is that I am not correctly setting the role for the user upon registration. My AspNetRoles table is correctly populated but AspNetUserRoles table is empty.

How can I troubleshoot this to find what is wrong with my application so I can use @User.IsInRole(...) instruction?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You say "even with the `Role` column in the AspNetUsers table of that user is `Admin`", but then say "AspNetUserRoles table is empty". If there's a join/cross reference table, then there wouldn't be a Role column on the AspNetUsers table.

Comment: @krillgar Thanks for your reply. I am not sure if I fully understood your point, but are you saying that my AspNetUsersRoles table should not be empty?

Comment: Yes. Since a User can have many Roles, and many Users will be in the same Role, there shouldn't be a Role column on the AspNetUsers table. Because your AspNetUserRoles table is empty, that's telling me that no Users actually have Roles assigned to them.

Comment: You can debug this by putting a breakpoint where you're checking `User.IsInRoles()`, and look at the `Roles` property on the user object. I'm 99.9999% certain that the collection will be empty.

Answer (score 3):

This worked perfectly fine for me.
Just make sure you've **seeded the roles in the database** and also the registered **user is assigned a role** and this should work fine.

````
        {
            <a asp-action="StudentDashboard" asp-controller="Home">Dashboard</a>
        }
        else
        if (User.IsInRole("College"))
        {
            <a asp-action="CollegeDashboard" asp-controller="Home">Dashboard</a>
        }
        else
        if (User.IsInRole("Manager"))
        {
            <a asp-action="AdminDashboard" asp-controller="Home">Dashboard</a>
        }
        else
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            <a asp-action="AdminDashboard" asp-controller="Home">Dashboard</a>
        }```
````

Answer (score 1):

i think you did not write or you write but in the wrong way this below code on global.asax :

```
    protected void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(Object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs e)
    {

        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //let us take out the username now                
                    string Email = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                    string roles = string.Empty;

                    using (DatabaseContext entities = new DatabaseContext())
                    {
                        var user = entities.TblUsers.Where(u => u.Email == Email).FirstOrDefault().IDRole;

                        //here
                        roles = entities.TblRoles.Where(x => x.IDRole == user).FirstOrDefault().RoleName;

                    }
                    //let us extract the roles from our own custom cookie

                    // and here
                    //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                    e.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                      new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(Email, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));

                }
                catch
                {

                    //somehting went wrong
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding below at the top of the view page:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

Alternatively:

```
@if(Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Admin"))
```